# jQuery only possible to execute once per page load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

My jQuery script is a popup window to my website when you click a button.
The buttons are in table, in a foreach loop. Things works just fine there.
The problem is, if i click product 1, the popup window works as it should, but when i close the window and try to popup it again, it not works. It will work again if refresh the page. It seems to work only once per button, then i need to refresh page..

The jQuery script is here:

```
;
            (function ($) {
                // DOM Ready
                $(function () {
                    // Binding a click event
                    // From jQuery v.1.7.0 use .on() instead of .bind()
                    $('.wiki-button').bind('click', function(e){
                    var $tr = $(e.currentTarget).closest('tr'), 
                    $content = $tr.find('#wiki-content');
                    $content.bPopup();
                    });
                });
            })(jQuery);
```

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:

Thanks a lot for all answers. The rest of code can you look at this pastebin code!
[Pastebin](http://pastebin.no/34bj)

Comment: Well, did you read the comment that you copied ? The thing about `.on()` and `.bind()` ? Did you give it a shot ? Also make sure you check your console after you click a button, I'm 99% sure there is going to be an error...

Comment: Sounds like bPopup() has some flags set that are not updated when popup is closed. I am not familiar with that plugin, but is there an explicit close() method or something similar? You may need to see what is done in that method and compare it to what happens when you close the popup the way you do.

Comment: What's your point? Using `on` is a recommendation, not a requirement.

Comment: Are you adding and removing `wiki-button` elements dynamically?

Comment: Can you check on the console of the browser if there are any reported errors?

Comment: @Barmar I presume that you're talking to me ? I'm not saying it's a requirement, I'm asking if he tried `on()` ...

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov Since `.bind` just calls `.on`, they're equivalent. There's little point in trying it.

Comment: @Barmar Cool, I'm not familiar with the implementation details of `.bind()`, will look into it. It seemed like a legit reason for an issue since it's specifically mentioned in the comments. Meanwhile I'd like to know if any errors are showing up in the console.

Comment: I have already tried on(), don't make a different. look the remaining code http://pastebin.no/34bj

Answer (score 0):

use following

```
$(document).on('click','.wiki-button', function(e){
```

Comment: We should find out whether these elements are added dynamically before saying this is the solution.

Comment: Yes I know, but this will work in all cases and He/she just want to do his work quickly that's why he has come to stackoverflow.

Comment: If the problem isn't related to dynamic elements, then this won't work any better than the original code.

Comment: Yeah, I agree..  There's more going on here -- it'd be helpful to see the rest of the code (or at least enough to see the root of the problem).

Comment: @DavidKirby , i updated the main post with a pastebin link to the loop code :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are repeating the id **wiki-content**

Sorry to add as answer.